# training and validation set in every epochs?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am new to CNN and deep learning, so sorry if my question does not make sense. I use generator for my training and validation set that augment my data too. if I use such a code to train my model, in every epochs I get different train and validation images. I want to know whether it is wrong or not. since I think that it is essential to train network with constant train and valid dataset in every epochs.

I appreciate any comments on choosing train and validation batch size too.

```
history= my_model.fit(data_generator(x_train,y_train, train_or_test='train', batch_size=16), 
              validation_data=next(data_generator(x_valid,y_valid,train_or_test='test',batch_size=8)),validation_steps=100,
                  epochs=100,steps_per_epoch=100,verbose = 1,
                  callbacks=[CSVLogger(os.path.join(folder(weights_folder), 'training_log.csv')),best_check , erlstop])
```

Comment: There is no problem in "shuffling" images for training and validation sets. Also, You can keep testing different batch_sizes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't need to be. However then, you might face overfitting, but you will only be able to tell after training and validation. I'm attaching a [link](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/22486/should-the-training-data-be-the-same-in-each-epoch) that will definitely answer the questions you have.

Comment: yes, exactly,  I face overfitting. after some  first epochs my valid loss starts growing up until its dice metric  becomes  nan. however it is good on training.

Comment: @ZSS I think going through the first answer in the link will help, it even has info about what your minibatch sizes can be